# Avoid duplication in data pulled from Cassandra

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Background: I am getting information from varius logfiles and a Cassandra table. The logfiles are fine, but fetching from the table gives me duplicates inside elasticsearch, as I can't get the rows added since sql_last_run.
How do I avoid duplication of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid this is to create your own document IDs by computing the SHA or MD5 of the raw log line.

That way the same log line, even if read repeatedly, will always produce the same ID and you won't get any duplicate documents anymore.

Another solution is to create another column in your tables with a unique GUID and use that value as the document IDs.

Comment: I have several document types, but have to do this for only one of them.
Is it possible to apply custom document_id to only that particular type, while retaining the default ones for the others?

Comment: I guess, it depends on how your loading pipeline looks like. Which tool are you using? Looks like you're using the ES JDBC loader, right?

Comment: Was using JDBC logstash input plugin. Used an if case for that cassandra type in logstash output config and added document_id there.
That solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out.